# Salesforce API missing fields, using describe_object

Tags: salesforce

I created the below to see my fields

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce


sf_conn = Salesforce(self.sf_conn_id)

fields = sf_conn.describe_object(self.object)['fields']
```

but when I print fields I notice some fields are not populating. Is there something I need to change in order to see them? This is an example of a field I'm not seeing: industry_field_c

Answer (score 0):

The Describe API respects object- and field-level security. You will receive the describe data only for fields and objects to which the authenticated user has at least read permission.

Hence, the most likely explanation is that you don't have access to `Industry_field__c`.

Comment: How do I 'edit' the permissions to get access? I would only need it for one user (me) to have this permission, is there documentation from Salesforce on this?

Comment: Check out [Data Security](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/data_security) on Trailhead.